# Вывод JSON в html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

С помощью такого ajax запроса получаю json:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var idFrom = 1;
       var idTo = 2;

       $.ajax({
           url: '/index.php',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType:'json',
           data: {action: 'showMessage', 'idFrom': idFrom, 'idTo': idTo},
           success: function (data) {
              data = JSON.parse(data);

                       ?????

           }
        });
      });
```

Результат в файле index.php `{"user1":"testeste"}{"user1":"test2"}`. И как теперь мне вывести результат в таблицу?

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Отправитель:</th>
     <th>Текст:</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="myTr">
      <td class="userName"></td>
      <td class="textMessage"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Чтобы в результате была таблица; `Отправитель`: `user1`, `Текст`:`testeste`?

Comment: Разделите задачу на несколько мелких частей, например, как я понял (может и неправильно, я в вебе не шарю) - 1. Парсинг JSON массива 2. Составление таблицы.

Comment: У вас уже в хтмл есть таблица и вам надо из js скрипта добавить в нее данные из json? Тогда задачу можно разделить так: достаем все json обьекты из json массива, берем у каждого ключ и значение, потом ищем элемент таблицы, и циклом вставляем данные в нее

Comment: @Flippy, идею я примерно понимаю, но как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(data);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var key in data[i]) {
    $("table.table tbody").append("<tr class='myTr'>" +
      "<td class='userName'>" + key + "</td>" +
      "<td class='textMessage'>" + data[i][key] + "</td>" +
      "</tr>");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за отклик. Но почему-то не работает, не могу понять почему. Выводится только `Отправитель`:     ,`Текст`

Answer (score 1):

Момент с разбором JSON-а опустил, суть метода: перебираем массив объектов и обращаемся к каждому свойству-значению, вставляем построчно в таблицу.

```js
var data = {
  "users": [{
    "username": "Vasya",
    "userid": 1
  }, {
    "username": "Petya",
    "userid": 10
  }, {
    "username": "Kolya",
    "userid": 15
  }, {
    "username": "Natashya",
    "userid": 13
  }]
};

$(data.users).each(function(index, item) {
  $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + item.username + '</td><td>' + item.userid + '</td></tr>');
});
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>UserID</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: json у меня формируется на сервере таким образом  `echo json_encode(array($userName => $row['message']));`  т.е. нет никаких "username" или "userid", а просто  `{'user1':'Hello'}`, `{'user2'}:{'Привет'}`.
Пытался как сделать как писал предыдущий комментатор, т.е. `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var key in data[i]) {
    $("table.table tbody").append("<tr class='myTr'>" +
      "<td class='userName'>" + key + "</td>" +
      "<td class='textMessage'>" + data[i][key] + "</td>" +
      "</tr>");
    break;
  }
}` Пройти по всем элементам и попутно выводить, но не работает

Comment: покажите что-нибудь кроме кусочка `{'user1':'Hello'}, {'user2'}:{'Привет'}` о вашем json-е, мне пока что непонятно как разобрать его. свой код я для примера написал, естественно к вас не будет такого же :-)

Comment: На сервере получаю данные из бд и в цикле добавляю  `while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {

    $fromMessage = ($row['fromMessage']);
    $userName = getUserName($fromMessage, $mysqli);
    echo json_encode(array($userName => $row['message']));
}` .  В консоли разработчика браузера echo выводит `{'user1':'Hello'}, {'user2'}:{'Привет'}`. Наверное все что могу сказать о своем json

Comment: `{'user1':'Hello'}, {'user2'}:{'Привет'}` ???

Comment: @Igor, т.е. `echo json_encode(array($userName => $row['message']));` возвращает `{'user1':'Hello'}, {'user2'}:{'Привет'}` (имя отправителя и текст сообщения). Надеюсь я понятно объясняю)