# Разбор JSON строки

Tags: jquery, json

Есть JSON строка с ответом от сервера такого вида

`[{"id":"1","buy":"Купить"},{"id":"2","buy":"Купить"},{"id":"3","profit":"Снять"},{"id":"4","profit":"Снять"},{"id":"5","time":"1 минута"}]`

Как разобрать элементы? К примеру 1 элемент мне нужно добавить в 1 div, 2 во второй div и т.д. если можно пример похожий.

Comment: пример вашей строки не валидный,  я так понимаю что между объектами `{}{}` должна быть запитая `{},{}`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ , https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: а как найти значение 1 элемента, 2-го и т.д? Не нашел этого!

Comment: надо вывести в div этот json ?

Comment: да, распределив 1-ый элемент в 1-ый div, 2-ой во 2-ой и т.д

Comment: вот смотри ответ Ди Ма : https://toster.ru/q/414934

Comment: вот тоже хороший ответ  : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671906/308951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const jsonStr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "buy": "Купить"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "buy": "Купить"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "profit": "Снять"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "profit": "Снять"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "time": "1 минута"
  }
];
const container = document.getElementById('container');

jsonStr.forEach(function(item) {
  const itemDiv = document.createElement('div');
  itemDiv.classList.add('card', 'm-2', 'p-2');
  itemDiv.id = item.id;
  // Заполняем содержимое div
  // разметку можно применять произвольную
  let innerHtml = '<dl>';
  // Если нужно вывести и значения ключей
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    innerHtml += `
      <dt>${key}</dt>
      <dd>${item[key]}</dd>
    `;
  });
  innerHtml += '</dl>';
  itemDiv.innerHTML = innerHtml;
  // Добавляем элемент. Родительский элемент можно
  // заменить на необходимый HTMLElement
  container.appendChild(itemDiv);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```